# Facebook review on a live web site

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, heroku

hopefully not a silly question, but I don't see a solution.

We currently have a live site that uses the Facebook API for login and are currently developing share facilities that will use public_actions and as such require the app to be reviewed.

Our problem is that the live site and development site do not share the same domain (development is on an heroku generated name appname-dev.herokuapp.com) so we can't add it to the allowed App Domains on the Facebook app. As such we were using a test app for development.

We can't point the main app at the development site as the live users wouldn't be able to login.

Are we able to get the app reviewed by pointing the reviewer to the development site, or should we perhaps point a sub-domain at the development site? Is waiting until it goes live the only option?

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1-

So you got two apps:

- App **A**, this is public/live: mywebsite.com
- App **B**, this is development only (this could be a child app, by the way): something-else.heroku.com

2-

You develop new features that require extended permissions on app **B**, but since it's development only, you *don't* need to submit for review (?).

At this point, app **A** should **NOT** be asking for extended permissions since you are not using your new features yet.

3a-

Once you are happy with the new features and pushed to production (i.e. should now be available on app **A**), you submit for review.

Obviously, since this is not yet approved, you shouldn't update the UI available to your normal users, but instead provide Facebook reviewers with direct link to the feature (could be a test page for instance). **OR** you could provide a screencast showing the new behavior.

---

3b-

Alternatively, you could simply have a staging subdomain on app **A**, that is basically a replica of your main website but with the latest features:

```
mywebsite.com <-- available to users
staging.mywebsite.com <-- send this to facebook review
```

Now if your *App Domain* is set to *mywebsite.com*, then *staging.mywebsite.com* should work fine since it's a subdomain.

Comment: Thanks very much for your reply. In the end we went with 3a and went live before requesting review.